# How to Create Django Project without default Django Database table

Tags: django

I'm trying to make Django project but when creating that Django Project There are serval table created in Database which I dont Want. I need Django Project Without any Default Database Table

Database tables are:

```
auth_group
auth_group_permission
auth_user
django_migration
django_admin_log
django_content_type
```

I tried Disabling 
django.contrib.admin
In Installed Apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # 'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    # 'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'data.apps.DataConfig',
]
```

The Expected result should be Django shouldn't create Default table in database

Comment: you will miss many features of django why do you want to do it?

Comment: I only want plain Django to Display data from Database table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the first migration you have to remove these apps from you your `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py` file:
    `django.contrib.admin`,
    `django.contrib.auth`,
    `django.contrib.contenttypes`,
    `django.contrib.sessions`,
but it is not recommended because you will loose many features of django

Comment: It's giving error 'No Installed app with label admin

Comment: you have to remove these apps after creating django project before the initial migrate.How did you do it ?

Comment: Thank you for reply I have created project and before initial migrate i'm removing this app and after this its throwing lookup error 'No Installed app with label admin'

Comment: @Shubham  `path('admin/', admin.site.urls),` also remove this from your urls.py

Comment: Thank You. Your solution has helped me but can you say by doing this which are the features of django will i miss

Comment: you will miss many features of django. You can use your custom admin page instead of django default admin site which is good but it is better to have other `default django apps` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` .Better look at django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/.

Comment: I will look into it Thank You

Comment: i tried your solution but now when I'm runnning my project its giving following error. django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: this is because you removed `django.contrib.contentypes` from your installed apps.You have to add that. As i already said it is not good to remove other apps except `django.contrib.admin` beacause we can make our own custom admin page for this.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/ look at this for more about content types.

Comment: But by adding all of these it will create Default Database table

Comment: @Shubham yes it will but it can be removed later while displaying in our template.But it will remain as it is on our database

Comment: But my requirement is it shouldn't create any table in my database. It should only read from my already created database. And display that data in Django view.